# Is there a way to transfer fmt:message to servlet?

Tags: java

I have an enum, let's say for fruits. The description/name of it varies between different languages (obviously). I tried to keep the localization to front-end only and put the description via fmt:message. Something like this:

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <c:set var="FruitEnum" value="${fruitArray}" />
    <c:forEach items="${FruitEnum}" var="fruit">
        <fmt:message key="input.fruit_${fruit}" var="fruit_label" />
        <option value="${fruit}"}>
            <c:out value="${fruit_label}"></c:out>
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Now I want to generate a PDF that prints some of the chosen values. Therefore I use a Servlet. I retrieve the values via `session.getAttribute()` which gives me the value but not the name.

**Is there a way to bind these localized Strings to the request/session to use them in a Servlet?**